# Angular 2 - creating global variables pulled from db

Tags: angular

Just getting to grips with the nuances of Angular 2 and one thing I'm trying to establish is the best practice for creating site wide variables that can be used in any component.

I am pulling variables from the db with a service. That service has a getVars() method which uses the Http.get() method to pull the data. My question is, rather than use that method each time I need the variables, can I use it once and store it in a constant variable ( or similar ) then call that anytime I need it. And would that be in the root module?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to know is that all the `Injectable` are `Singleton` in an Angular 2 application. You can just retrieve your value with your method (basically on initialization, check `APP_INITIALIZER`), store it in a property of your object and then retrieve it everywhere you inject your service. Here's a short example for a configuration service.

config.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
    private _config: Object;
    private http: Http;

    constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    }

    get(optionName: any) {
        return this._config[optionName];
    }


    load() {
        this.http = this.injector.get(Http);

        let observable = this.http.get('dist/config/configuration.json')
            .map(res => res.json());

        observable.subscribe(config => this._config = config);
        return observable.toPromise();
    }
}
```

In your App.module.ts in your `Providers` array

```
    ConfigService,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => () => config.load(),
        deps: [ConfigService],
        multi: true
    },
```

Then you can just inject your service into every Component and access the variable directly with configService.get('yourVariable')